# CakePHP: Saving HABTM data MySQL error

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

I'm trying to build a form in a view that saves data to 3 different tables that all have a many to many relations in my MySQL database, and hasAndBelongsToMany relations in the CakePHP models.
However I try to do this though, it doesn't work, it either only saves the data from the controller I'm working in, or gives me the following MySQL error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`agenda`.`timetables_weekschedules`, CONSTRAINT `fk_weekschedules_has_timetables_timetables1` FOREIGN KEY (`timetable_id`) REFERENCES `timetables` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTIO)
```

This is the form in my View/Weekschedules/jeffrey.ctp (will be properly renamed when it's working):

```
<div class="form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Weekschedule'); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Create workschedule'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo "<h1>Period</h1>";
        echo $this->Form->input('Period.name');
        echo $this->Form->input('Period.description');
        echo $this->Form->input('Period.startdatetime');
        echo $this->Form->input('Period.enddatetime');
        echo "<h1>Weekschedule</h1>";
        echo $this->Form->input('Weekschedule.name');
        echo $this->Form->input('Weekschedule.oddeven');
        echo "<h1>Timetable</h1>";
        echo $this->Form->input('Timetable.weekday');
        echo $this->Form->input('Timetable.starttime');
        echo $this->Form->input('Timetable.endtime');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
```

When the form inputs are like this, it throws the MySQL error, and when I format the inputs that are not in this controller like Period.0.name it just only saves the Weekschedule data.

This is how the jeffrey action in Controller/WeekschedulesController.php currently looks like, I only set the Weekschedule id as a test because I want to create a new Weekschedule, but that also doesn't work. I also tried saveAll() and saveAssociated() instead of the save() function and tried 'deep'=>true, nothing works.

```
public function jeffrey() {
    $this->Weekschedule->recursive = 2;

    $this->request->data['Weekschedule']['id'] = 95;
    debug($this->request->data);

    if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Weekschedule->save($this->request->data);
    }
}
```

My Weekschedule model is default CakePHP bake code:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Weekschedule Model
 *
 * @property Period $Period
 * @property Timetable $Timetable
 */
class Weekschedule extends AppModel {

/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $displayField = 'name';


    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * hasAndBelongsToMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Period' => array(
            'className' => 'Period',
            'joinTable' => 'periods_weekschedules',
            'foreignKey' => 'weekschedule_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'period_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
        ),
        'Timetable' => array(
            'className' => 'Timetable',
            'joinTable' => 'timetables_weekschedules',
            'foreignKey' => 'weekschedule_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'timetable_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
        )
    );

}
```

And this is the line in my routes.php:

```
// Jeffrey's test page
Router::connect('/jeffrey', array('controller' => 'weekschedules', 'action' => 'jeffrey'));
```

I wanted to post a screenshot of my  database diagram, but since I'm new here I can't post images, so I'll try to describe it:

There's a periods table with the following columns:

- id (INT)
- name (VARCHAR(45))
- description (TEXT)
- startdatetime (DATETIME)
- enddatetime (DATETIME)
- created (DATETIME)
- modified (DATETIME)

Then there's a periods_weekschedules join table with the following columns:

- period_id (INT)
- weekschedule_id (INT)

And the following foreign keys:

- fk_periods_has_weekschedules_periods1: periods_weekschedules.period_id -> periods.id
- fk_periods_has_weekschedules_weekschedules1: periods_weekschedules.weekschedule_id -> weekschedules.id

Then there's a weekschedules table with the following columns:

- id (INT)
- name (VARCHAR(45))
- orderNr (INT)
- oddeven (VARCHAR(45))
- created (DATETIME)
- modified (DATETIME)

Then there's a timetables_weekschedules join table with the following columns:

- weekschedule_id (INT)
- timetable_id (INT)

And the following foreign keys:

- fk_weekschedules_has_timetables_weekschedules1: timetables_weekschedules.weekschedule_id -> weekschedules.id
- fk_weekschedules_has_timetables_timetables1: timetables_weekschedules.timetable_id -> timetables.id

And finally a timetables table with the following columns:

- id (INT)
- weekday (INT)
- starttime (TIME)
- endtime (TIME)
- created (DATETIME)
- modified (DATETIME)

Since I'm a beginner with CakePHP, I hope this is enough information to help you help me, thanks in advance!
Jeffrey

Comment: The error message contains a table named 'agenda' which I can't see in the rest of your problem description.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the database name is agenda.
Also, I only put the 5 tables that matter for this problem in the description, there's a total of 24 tables in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to debug such big relations without having the full code and testing it. 
But if everything fails you can manually sort the data from your

```
$this->request->data
```

and manually save the results for each model.

Also take a look at the very detailed guide: [How to save HABTM data in CakePHP](http://patisserie.keensoftware.com/en/pages/how-to-save-habtm-data-in-cakephp)

Comment: Thank you! The function to overload saveAssociated did the trick, at first the saved data wasn't correct, but after formatting the form inputs not in the WeekschedulesController like Period.0.name it saved all the data how I want.

Comment: Thanks for the answer buddy, you've earned the bounty :)